# How to get error code from modbus slave device with NModbus4 framework?

Tags: c#, modbus

I use NMOdbus framework to work with modbus rtu network, but i can't find any example how to get the code of failed requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean the exception cause?  Like "Illegal Data Address" or "Unsupported Function"?

You should receive a SlaveExceptionResponse message whenever the slave device reports a failure.  The value you want is SlaveExceptionCode.

Here's the relevant class file on GitHub -

[SlaveExceptionResponse.cs](https://github.com/NModbus4/NModbus4/blob/portable-3.0/NModbus4/Message/c)